# Free Pascal - Problem solving query (not syntax) - how to approach the next phase of this loop

Tags: for-loop, freepascal

I have more of a 'problem solving' question than a syntax related problem.

Briefly, I'm creating a program that will read a text file full of words (that may feasibly be a list of passwords), one word per line - I'll be using ReadLn for that bit in a loop. For every word it finds, I want it to add "an amount" of obfuscation in line with how users these days will use '3' instead of 'E' in their passwords, or '1' instead of 'I'. I work in the IT security field and password breaking is often part of it and that's what the program is for.

I have managed to create the program so far that it generates a LEET table full of many different values for each letter of the alphabet and stacks them in a StringGrid that I can access as part of the process (and it is also outputted visually to a table).

```
type
TLetters = 'A'..'Z';
    TLeet = array[TLetters] of TStringList;

var
  SourceFileName, str : string;
  StartIndexFile : TextFile;

  i    : TLetters;
  leet : TLeet;
  s    : string;
  n, o, ColumnSize    : integer;           

begin

for i in TLetters do
  leet[ i ] := TStringList.Create;   

// The next sequence of loops populates the string grid by counting the number of     characters for each letter of the alphabet and then inserting them down, column by column and row by row...

//Letter A:

s := '4 @ /-\ /\ ^ aye ∂ ci λ Z';
ColumnSize := wordcount(s,[' ']);
o := 0;
  for n := 0 to ColumnSize do
    leet['A'].Add(ExtractWord(n,s,[' ']));
      for o := 0 to ColumnSize do
        StringGrid1.Cells[1,o] := Leet['A'][o];

// And so on for B - Z

// ... then an OpenDialog that opens the source text file to read. Got that sorted

//  A load of file opening stuff and then the obsfucation
        repeat
           Readln(StartIndexFile, Str);
           LblProgress.Caption := ('Parsing Index File...please wait');
             OBSFUCATE THE WORDS HERE TO SOME EXTENT
             // but now I have hit a barrier....
       until(EOF(StartIndexFile));
```

My problem is this : given the word 'Edward', for example, how do I decide to what level I should obfuscate it? Just the first letter 'E' to be replaced with a '3', and nothing more perhaps? Or the first two letters 'E' and 'd' to be replaced with ALL the values in the LEET table for both of the letters E and d (meaning dozens of new words would be generated from 'Edward', and so on), or all the values for 'E' but nothing else...the list goes on. Potentially, for every word, I could create thousands of additional one's! A 100Gb source file would soon become terabytes!

In other words, I need to set "a level" for which the program will function, that the user can decide. But I'm not sure how to structure that level?

So I'm not sure how to make it work? I didn't really think it through enough before I started. My initial thoughts were "It would be cool to have a program that would take an index of words from a computer, and then generate variations of every word to account for people who obfuscate characters." but having come to code it, I've realised it's a bigger job than I thought and I am now stuck at the section for actually 'LEETing my input file'!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a level (0-10) as input.
0: replace nothing
10: replace all letters with LEET letters.

Depending on the length of the word, you calculate how many letters to replace and just replace random letters in the word, so that you not always replace the first letter for level 1 etc.

Comment: Yes, food for thought, for sure. Thanks